# NewLine replacement c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a windows phone application. In the application I have a textbox whose acceptsreturn property is set to true.

What I want to do is create a string from the textbox and replace the new lines with a specific character, something like `"NL"`

I've tried the following but none of them worked.

```
string myString = myTextBox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"NL");
string myString = myTextBox.Text.Replace("\n","NL");
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the newline character you are after, and not `carriage return` - \r? Does `string myString = myTextBox.Text.Replace("\r","NL");` work? Environment.NewLine is usually `\r\n` on Windows for example, so you've tried \n and \r\n!

Comment: Why didn't it work?  Was there an exception?  Or was the output not formatted as you wanted?

Comment: well it didnt cause an exception, it just didnt work. newline didnt get replaced

Comment: string myString = myTextBox.Text.Replace("\r","NL"); worked! Thank you a lot, ive been searching for this the whole morning. I had no idea that the carriage return \r existed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with  windows phone(or silverlight), but try to split with `\r` instead:

```
string myString = myTextBox.Text.Replace("\r","NL");
```

[Why does a Silverlight TextBox use \r for a newline instead of Environment.Newline (\r\n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610400/why-does-a-silverlight-textbox-use-r-for-a-newline-instead-of-environment-newli)

Comment: Yes that was the answer after all! Thanks!

Comment: Is this classed as duplicate? Is windows phone effectively silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Consider replacing different types of line breaks to handle all the possibilities

```
string myString myTextBox.Replace("\r\n", "NL").Replace("\n", "NL").Replace("\r", "NL");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
var myString = myTextBox.Text.Replace("\r","NL");
```

This is for compatibility with every operating systems.

Comment: Thank you sir!! that was the answer after all

Answer (score 0):

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022571/how-to-deal-with-the-new-line-character-in-the-silverlight-textbox) with a similar topic had a quite elegant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3022843/674700) you might consider interesting to use:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

myTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(myTextBox.Text, @"\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n", "NL");
```